# How to update CPInformationTemplate when the data is updated

Tags: ios, swift, carplay

I'm working with CarPlay EV Charging app.

I want to show Charging progress in `CPInformationTemplate`.

My concern is, whenever the charge status is updated, I want to update the information shown in `CPInformationTemplate`.

I'm not able to find any solution on this yet.
I only see that only `CPListTemplate` is being updated for EV Charging category app.

Am I using the right template for showing Charging detail or am I missing anything.

Here's a screenshot of demo project of mine which shows Charging info in `CPInformationTemplate`

[image: Charge detail screen]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you can update the `CPInformationTemplate`'s `items` property "...to update the items that the template displays" (see [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/carplay/cpinformationtemplate/3664504-items)).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it worked!